# Excel VBA save screenshot

Tags: vba, excel

I try to take a screenshot of a Worksheet in Excel with VBA code and then to save it in a specified path, but I do not manage to save it properly...

```
Sub My_Macro(Test, Path)
  Dim sSheetName As String
  Dim oRangeToCopy As Range
  Dim FirstCell As Range, LastCell As Range

  Worksheets(Test).Activate
  Set LastCell = Cells(Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
      Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column)
  Set FirstCell = Cells(Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=LastCell, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
      SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
      Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=LastCell, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
      SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Column)

  sSheetName = Test ' worksheet to work on

  With Worksheets(sSheetName)
      .Range(FirstCell, LastCell).CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
      .Export Filename:=Path + Test + ".jpg", Filtername:="JPG"
  End With

End Sub
```

Excel doesn't want to execute the method .Export... directly after taking the screenshot.
So I tried to paste the picture in a new chart. Excel save the chart picture at the right place with a chart on my picture... I also tried to paste it in a temporary worksheet but Excel doesn't want to export it...

Any idea

Comment: I do not think that jpg is a valid export format for Excel (see the list when you try to export an Excel sheet manually) So Excel does not know what to do when you force it to do so in code.

Comment: See here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/233108-visual-basic-applications-code-export-image-file-preferably-jpg.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was busy with the the idea Luboš Suk had.

Just change the size of the Chart. See script below.

```
Sub My_Macro(Test, Path)


 Test = "UNIT 31"
    Dim sSheetName As String
    Dim oRangeToCopy As Range
    Dim FirstCell As Range, LastCell As Range

    Worksheets(Test).Activate

    Set LastCell = Cells(Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
        Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column)

    Set FirstCell = Cells(Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=LastCell, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
        Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=LastCell, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Column)

    sSheetName = Test ' worksheet to work on

    With Worksheets(sSheetName).Range(FirstCell, LastCell)

        .CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
        'Getting the Range height
        PicHeight = .Height
        'Getting the Range Width
        PicWidth = .Width

        ''.Export Filename:=Path + Test + ".jpg", Filtername:="JPG"   'REMOVE THIS LINE


    End With


    With Worksheets(sSheetName)

        'Creating the Chart
        .ChartObjects.Add(30, 44, PicWidth, PicHeight).Name = "TempChart"

        With .ChartObjects("TempChart")

            'Pasting the Image
            .Chart.Paste
            'Exporting the Chart
            .Chart.Export Filename:=Path + Test + ".jpg", Filtername:="JPG"

        End With

        .ChartObjects("TempChart").Delete

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks guys, it works and does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I was making something similar months ago. I needed to make a screenshot of particular range and export it into file. After hours of headsmashing into table i found solution with `.chart.export` which seems most user friendly to me. Please take a look at my code, i think you can easily update it to your need. Simple thought is to create chart, paste whatever you wana to take a screenshot of in it, export chart to picture and then delete id. Simple and elegant. Feel free to ask if there is some problem

```
Sub takeScreen()
    Dim mainSheet As Worksheet
    Set mainSheet = Sheets("Input-Output")

    Dim path As String
    path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    If Dir(path & "\figures\", vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Directory figures not found. Cannot save image."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With mainSheet
        .ChartObjects.Add(30, 44, 765, 868).Name = "exportChart"
        With .ChartObjects("exportChart")
            .Chart.ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlNone
            .Chart.ChartArea.Fill.Visible = False
            mainSheet.Range(mainSheet.Cells(4, "B"), mainSheet.Cells(60, "L")).CopyPicture
            .Chart.Paste
            .Chart.Export fileName:=path & "\figures\" & "fatigue_summary.png ", FilterName:="png"
        End With
        .ChartObjects("exportChart").Delete
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

According to your comment, i think you can calculate chart size from row/column size and their count. Or you can resize chart using cells position and size attributes. (`look for .cells().width, .cells().height,.cells().top, .cells().left`)

Comment: Hi Luboš Suk, thank you for your answer. I also did it this way. It works but the problem is that when I just paste one row of data in the chart I get a big white space at the end of the chart and so also on saved picture. I do not know whether it is possible to resize the chart to the size of the screenshot....

Comment: Not exactly sure now, but you know size of row and number of rows you copy. So from that you can calculate size and change chart size according to it

Comment: @LubošSuk just paste and check the size of the image and then delete it. have a look at my answer. Was also thinking about using a Shell App and pasting into paint but it wasn't working, that is why I took so long

Comment: @Jean-PierreOosthuizen  great idea. Code can be optimized on some parts, but good solution :) (but imho i will rather compute size and do not create another image and then delete it. But i will make some time and test your solution against mine, im curious)

Comment: You could try check the pixel size of the selection and then set the chart as suxh

Comment: `Range().Height` works perfectly and then you just use that value when creating your chart. New script has been inserted