# Save captured screenshot as JPG with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a macro that will capture a screen with keyboard events. After that, it will save the screenshot to an Excel file.

Here is the code:

```
DoEvents
    keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0&
    keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0&
DoEvents

capturesFile.Worksheets(capturesFile.Worksheets.Count).Paste Destination:=curWS.Cells(rowNum + 2, 2)
```

I want my macro to save the same screenshot as a JPG file in a folder, before saving it to the Excel file.

More information: I am capturing any random screen (Desktop, Skype, Outlook, some folder, some Web page, it could be anything.) I want to save the screenshot to a folder. Saving the screenshot as a JPG file has no relation with the Excel file.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA save screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34062242/excel-vba-save-screenshot)

Comment: Hello PEH! Thanks for your comment. I am capturing any random screen (Desktop, Skype, Outlook, some folder, some Web page, it could be anything.) I want to save the screenshot to a folder. Saving the screenshot as a JPG file has no relation with the Excel file. Do you know how that can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had small difficulties with the solution of PEH, so I used his method to make this version. On my computer (Window 10, Office 2010 is running well.)

```
Sub SaveScreenshotAsJpeg()
    'make your screenshot here (so it is in the clipboard) …
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    ws.Paste ' Past to the worksheet. It is a shape.
    Dim TempPicture As Shape
    On Error Resume Next ' Test if it succedded. Clipboard could be empty or text ...
        Set TempPicture = ws.Shapes(1)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TempPicture Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Pasting picture was not successfull (not on clipboard). End."
        ws.Delete ' delete the unused worksheet
        Exit Sub
    End If
    TempPicture.CopyPicture 'copy again, since it was removed from clipboard.
    'create a chart with the exact size of the picture
    Dim TempChart As ChartObject
    Set TempChart = ws.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, TempPicture.Width, TempPicture.Height)
    With TempChart.Chart 'paste the screenshot into the chart
        .ChartArea.Select
        .Paste
    End With
    'export the chart
    TempChart.Chart.Export Filename:="C:\Temp\test.jpg", FilterName:="JPEG"
    ws.Delete ' delete the unused worksheet with all its objects
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks PEH for providing the basic code, but unfortunately, it did not work on my computer. Thanks a lot Viktor for modifying PEH's code! Your code works on my computer. I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Since I believe there is no direct way to save this into a file, there is the following workaround:

1. We insert the picture into a worksheet (can be any worksheet or a temporary).
2. We read the `width` and `height` of the picture (and delete it).
3. We create a chart with the exact size of the picture.
4. We paste the picture into that chart.
5. We export that chart to jpeg.

#### Why such a complicated workaround?

- We cannot save pictures directly, but charts have an export method (so we can use that as a trick).
- We need to know the width and height to create the chart in the correct size (otherwise your picture is stretched.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveScreenshotAsJpeg()

    'make your screenshot here (so it is in the clipboard) …

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Tabelle1 'define your sheet (this can be a temporary sheet)

    'paste the screenshot as picture
    ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial

    Dim TempPicture As Object
    Set TempPicture = Selection

    'get height and width of the picture
    Dim PicWidth As Double
    PicWidth = shp.width
    Dim PicHeight As Double
    PicHeight = shp.Height

    'delete the picture
    TempPicture.Delete

    'create a chart with the exact size of the picture
    Dim TempChart As ChartObject
    Set TempChart = Tabelle1.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, PicWidth, PicHeight)

    'paste the screenshot into the chart
    TempChart.Chart.Paste

    'export the chart
    TempChart.Chart.Export Filename:="C:\Temp\test.jpg", FilterName:="JPEG"

    'delete the chart
    objchart1.Delete
End Sub
```