# Macro VBA Button to save screenshot of Dashboard in Sheet in JPG on Excel (using version 16.67 on Mac)

Tags: excel, vba, button, screenshot, dashboard

I am trying to make a button with **VBA** which automatically creates a **screenshot** of my **dashboard** presented in my worksheet and saves it as a separate **JPG** file.
I am using a Mac with Excel version 16.67.

The idea is that the button is able to do the following:

- The button should select the range D4:AG175.
- The file must be in JPG.
- The location of the file could be in the same map as where the
  Dashboard document is located (or on the Desktop, also fine).
- The name of the file should be "='Filter Employee Week'!B2" + "='Filter
  Employee Week'!B1" + ".jpg"

The "'Filter Employee Week'!B1 and B2" is a name selected from a slicer, which is connected to a pivot table.

**So in summary:**
The button takes a screenshot of the dashboard in the range D4 to AG175, it must be saved as a JPG in the same folder as the dashboard and the name should idyllically be the name of the employee selected in B2 and B1 (which are imported from a pivot table on a different sheet but presented by a connected slicer).

Can anyone help me with this code? I tried different codes from other users with problems that are comparable to this one, however, I can not get it fixed myself.

I am not able to solve this problem with the solutions presented at this question myself:
[Using Excel VBA Macro To Capture + Save Screenshot of Specific Area In Same File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904385/using-excel-vba-macro-to-capture-save-screenshot-of-specific-area-in-same-file)

[Save captured screenshot as JPG with vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62275372/save-captured-screenshot-as-jpg-with-vba)

Comment: If the cells are on screen why not consider Automator? As you don't seem to want to edit existing code you have found.

Comment: @SolarMike I really need the button within the excel file, therefore I do not think (or know) that Automator will do the job.